# PHP ftp upload times out(File is 12 byte)

Tags: php, ftp

I have a problem creating a local file, then uploading it to ftp server.

Here is my code:

```
    $file = 'test';

    $string = $phone.','.$y.','.$z;

    $fp = fopen($file, 'w+');
    fwrite($fp, $string);
    fclose($fp);

    $fp = fopen($file, 'r');

    $conn_id = ftp_connect('domain');

    ftp_login($conn_id, 'user', 'pass');

    if (ftp_fput($conn_id, $file, $fp, FTP_BINARY)) {

    } else {

    }

    ftp_close($conn_id);
    fclose($fp);
    unlink($file);
```

I dont get any error, I just exceed memory. I dont have any other problems with the ftp server, anywhere else but when I am uploading. As I said the file is only 12 bytes.

Comment: how do you know you "exceed memory" ?

Comment: Thats the message i get.

Comment: post the exact error message